# T-SQL For GRANT View ONLY to Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I write or grant a permission to a user to only view stored procedures? We don't want users dropping, editing or modifying procs.

Comment: Do you want the user to see the stored  procedure code or just execute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK you have to do 2 things to achieve what you are looking for.

First you have to create an execute role, that grant a user to just execute and see stored procedures on your database.

```
CREATE ROLE db_executor
GRANT EXECUTE TO db_executor
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_executor', 'username'
```

Than you have to give to the user the permission to see them in this way, that is also described in this article [Grant permissions to view stored procedure text](http://sqlserverimpressions.blogspot.ch/2008/10/grant-permissions-to-view-stored.html)

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON YourStoredProcedureName TO [UserName]
```

Answer (score 0):

With stored procedures you want to grant `EXEC` permission.

```
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.Proc_Name TO UserName
```

unless other permissions are granted to the user, users will not be able to modify, or drop the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

More simply, it is View Definition on the database, schema, or object that is required, depending on how granular you wish to implement it.  To grant on just the stored procedures it would be at the object level if the user does not already have implicit View Definition as a member of fixed role such as db_datareader.  If the intent is just for stored procedures, then I suggest building a role for this.

```
Create role [ViewDefinitionOnModules] authorization [dbo];
Grant view definition on [schema].[procedure] to [ViewDefinitionOnModules];
Alter role [ViewDefinitionOnModules] add member [database_user_name];
```